# Why work done against gravity is independent of it's path aquired?

Tags: forces, newtonian-gravity, work, potential-energy, conservative-field

I can't understand why work done against gravity does not depend on it's path acquired.

Comment: Please explain what *exactly* you do not understand about whatever explanation you're read, since it's rather hard to tell currently what you really want to know.

Answer (score 1):

It only pulls downwards. The path doesn't matter, only the height does (the vertical displacement)

If you move sideways, gravity has no effect on your motion. Pushing a box horizontally will make it continue forever on a smooth icy surface. Gravity doesn't stop it - it does no work on it. Friction may stop it. Friction can do work in it. But not gravity.

Only vertical displacements are affected by gravity. Only those can gravity do work on.

Answer (score 0):

The gravitational field is a conservative vector field. 
See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field) for a full mathematical description, but the important point is that line integrals are path independent, i.e. the choice of any path between two points does not change the value of the line integral.
When calculating the work done by the gravitational field when moving between points $a$ and $b$ in one dimension you're really calculating
$$ W = \int_{a}^{b} F(x) \, dx$$
Which is path independent as $F$ is conservative.

Answer (score 0):

Gravitational force is type of conservative force and all type of conservative forces depends on the displacement and not on the path traveled by it . It is because conservative forces have particular direction and not like friction force whose directions is always opposite to direction of motion.
     Examples of conservative force -gravitational force, electromagnetic force .
  Non conservative force -friction ,drag force.